# Cannot fetch item in NSFileProvider (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider

In fetchContents(..) method, I download file item from server by session.downloadTask.
And i copy file from response url to temporary url (which is created from NSFileProviderManager.temporaryURL). After this, it's certain that file contents of temporary url is not 0byte (same length with downloaded file) And then i call completionHandler with this temporary url, file provider item. But i cannot open file in finder with error msg - cannot open because the file is empty.
(I thought that it's about itemVersion problem, so i changed contentVersion temporarily, and after that, when i rebuild app, it starts to download item in finder and successfully download the file. And i can even open the file. But when i click another file to open it, i cannot open it with msg - file is empty.)

```swift
let task = downloadItem(named: filename) { url, error in
      let dataURL = makeTemporaryURL()

      do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: dataURL)
        completionHandler(dataURL, item, nil)
      }
      catch let error as NSError {
        completionHandler(nil, nil, Error.fileDownloadFailed)
      }
    }
    task.progress.cancellationHandler = { completionHandler(nil, nil, NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSUserCancelledError)) }
     
    return task.progress
```

Comment: Where does a guy named 'downloadItem(named:)' come from?

Comment: It just downloads file from server. Downloaded file is saved in temporary url, so i copy it to another path and return this path to completion handler.

Comment: I just cannot understand these - 1) When i click file, it starts to download, and after that process i cannot open the file because the file is empty. 2) When i change the content version of item in my code, temporarily, the file starts to download without clicking file, and it goes well and i can open the downloaded file.